# SSH host < script.sh - not work with expect

Tags: macos, shell, ssh, expect

I have this script:

```
expect -c "spawn ssh $sshUserName@$ipTestLion; expect \"*?asswor?:*\" {send \"$sshUserPasswort\\r\"; interact};" < $path2script/sshEvents.sh
```

This doesn't work. Somebody know why?

Comment: How do you find it to be not working? What error do you get? Are the variables set as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add another expect before interact:

```
expect -c "spawn ssh $sshUserName@$ipTestLion; expect \"*?asswor?:*\" {send \"$sshUserPasswort\\r\"; expect \"*:~*\" {interact;};};" < $path2script/sshEvents.sh
```

Also make sure you have the permission to create a file in `/Users/admin/Test/` and that the directory exists.

Comment: @user2746831 Please try this one and add post errors you may find.